# Computing mixed hodge structure using different extension of the constant sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $U$ be a non-compact smooth algebraic variety, and let $U\hookrightarrow X$ be a smooth compactification such that $D=X\setminus U$ is SNC. The connection $(\mathcal{O}_X,d)$ is the canonical Deligne extension of the connection $(\mathcal{O}_U,d)$. In this way the logarithmic De Rham complex $\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)$, which is used to define the MHS on $H^\bullet(U)$, is associated to the canonical Deligne extension.

If $D=\bigcup_{i=1}^qD_i$ with the $D_i$ irreducible components, and $m_1,\dots,m_q\in \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$, there are also the extensions
$$\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{m}}:=\mathcal{O}_X(\sum_{i=1}^q-m_iD_i),$$
each equipped with a logarithmic connection for which the residue along $D_i$ is $m_i$, and the natural map
$$\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{0}}=\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\to \Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{m}}$$
is a quasi isomorphism, hence both can be used to compute the cohomology of $U$.

Since the weight filtration can be defined in terms of the canonical truncation, which is well-defined on the derived category, I think that we can define the weight filtration on $H^\bullet(U)$ in terms of $\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{m}}$. However, I am not sure how the definition of the Hodge filtration can be phrased in terms of $\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{m}}$ in such a way that under the quasi-isomorphism above, it gives the correct filtration on $H^\bullet(U)$. The stupid truncation is not well-defined up to quasi-isomorphism, so applying it directly to $\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}^{\mathbf{m}}$ will not give the correct answer. So I wonder what the correct way to define the Hodge filtration is.

Edit: I think that the answer is contained in "Equations Differentielles a Points Singuliers Reguliers". The correct filtration to consider should be the "order of poles" filtration, as in 3.12.2 of loc.cit.